# Objective-C Blocks, C++ Variables and async code

Tags: c++, objective-c, asynchronous, pass-by-reference, objective-c-blocks

I'm having an issue while glueing together c++ vars with obj-c async code on iOS.

The real problem is located in the async code, I'm using third-party libraries built in C++ that expect object references, e.g.:

```
- (void) processFrame:(cv::Mat &)mat;
```

My problem real problem is how to call this ? I need to create the c++ object on a different thread and pass it to the async code, a bit like this:

```
__block cv::Mat mat(videoRect.size.height, videoRect.size.width, CV_8UC4, baseaddress, 0);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self processFrame:mat];
        });
```

Which give an error (Bad access), the problem is (I guess) the object is destroyed before the method runs, so I tried creating the object in the heap:

```
__block cv::Mat *mat= new cv::Mat(videoRect.size.height, videoRect.size.width, CV_8UC4, baseaddress, 0);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self processFrame:(*mat)];
        });
```

And still:

```
__block cv::Mat *mat= new cv::Mat(videoRect.size.height, videoRect.size.width, CV_8UC4, baseaddress, 0);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self processFrame:mat];
        });
```

I get keeping "Bad access" errors all the time

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

The `__block` qualifier tells the compiler to not copy the object for the block so that is why it is failing. If you are not reassigning `mat` or are not trying to prevent an unnecessary retain/copy operation then you should remove `__block`.

```
cv::Mat mat(videoRect.size.height, videoRect.size.width, CV_8UC4, baseaddress, 0);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self processFrame:mat];
        });
```

The examples where you create a `new cv::Mat` may be failing because you may be deleting `mat` too soon.

```
__block cv::Mat *mat= new cv::Mat(videoRect.size.height, videoRect.size.width, CV_8UC4, baseaddress, 0);
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self processFrame:mat];
            //mat would need to be deleted here
        });
delete mat; //If you are doing this, you will likely get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, I still have the same issues, even when I create the object in the heap... How should I pass a "heap object" to a method that expect an object reference (like cv::Mat & mat) ?

Comment: For a heap object pass it like this `[self processFrame:*mat];`, then you can `delete mat;` right after that call if you no use for it any longer.

Comment: Tried that before, still have the same error :( I will just try to use another library that lets me avoid mixing C++ and Obj-C :) Thanks for the help

Comment: This should work maybe try posting more of the relevant code.